# Unable to initialize iOS AppDelegate.cs with XFormsApplicationDelegate

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am creating an iOS application using Xamarin.Forms.Labs.iOS library.

I followed the steps as presented in this link https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki

and replaced

```
UIApplicationDelegate
```

with

```
XFormsApplicationDelegate
```

in my AppDelegate.cs.

Here is my AppDelegate.cs :

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : XFormsApplicationDelegate
{
    UIWindow window;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Forms.Init();

        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        window.RootViewController = App.GetMainPage().CreateViewController();

        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}
```

and my Main.cs file has

```
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.

        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my implementation ? I added all the assemblies and the code compiles without any errors. The app won't start and crashes with the following exception.

**Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named AppDelegate is loaded.**

Kindly, guide me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: What version are you using

Comment: xamarin.forms.labs version : 1.2.0  and Xamarin Studio version : 5.5.4 (build 15)

Comment: It seems to a known issue https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11272 try to turn off reference counting in the project properties -> ios build

Comment: I did browse those things before asking here. I hope there will be some solution to be found here.

Comment: By turning it off did it work?

Comment: Its already turned off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68123/discussion-between-indish-cholleti-and-sievajet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so silly. I just had to do rebuild instead of build to make that work.